# Shadow for shapes in tkinter canvas (python3)

Tags: python-3.x, canvas, tkinter

I am trying to make a program to make a pattern in tkinter and canvas for which whenever I create an object, the object should cast a shadow behind it. It should be similar to the image below. I don't know if it is possible, and where to start.

[image]

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: If you want to have transparency effects, you will have to create an image with PIL then display it in the canvas. Otherwise, your question is too broad, for instance will all the objects be rectangles? If so, it's a bit easier and you can just draw lines around them with decreasing alpha value in PIL.

Comment: Only rectangles for now. I'll try to use the lines idea.. Thanks!